# Splitting lines by delimiter in large file

Tags: linux, file, split, line, delimiter

I have a file in this format:

```
a(tab)b(tab)c
```

some lines do not have a `c` column

What I need to do is take the `b` column out of every line? What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use a regex.... e.g. `\w+\t(\w+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut` to extract the second field (tab is the default delimiter for `cut`):

```
cut -f2 file
```